# can't understand how does scala operation functions in Apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time, rdd, operation

**hello everyone,**

so I started to learn about Apache spark architecture and I understand how the data flow works in higher-level.

what I learn is that spark jobs work on stages that have tasks to operate on RDDS in which they are created with lazy transformations starting from the Spark console. *(correct me if I'm wrong)*

what I didn't get it :

- there are other types of data structures in Spark: Data Frame and Dataset, and there are functions to manipulate them,

  **so what is the relation between those functions and the tasks applied on RDDs ?**
- coding with Scala has operations on RDD which is logic as far as I know, and there is also other types of data structure that I can do operations on them and manipulate them like list, Stream, vector, etc...  so my question is

  **so how can spark execute these operations if they are not applied on RDDS ?**
- I have an estimation of time-complexity of each algorithm operating on any type of data structure of Scala referring to the official documents but I can't find the estimation of time-complexity of operations on RDDS, for example, count() or ReduceKey() applied in RDDS.

  **why we can't we evaluate exactly the complexity of Spark-app, and is it possible to evaluate elementary tasks complexities ?**

### ***more formally, what are RDDS and what is the relation between them and everything in Spark***

if someone can clarify to me this confusion of information, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

**so what is the relation between those functions and the tasks applied on RDDs ?**
DataFrames, Datasets, and RDD are three API from Spark. Check out [this link](https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-dataset/)

**so how can spark execute these operations if they are not applied on RDDS?**
RDD are structural Data structures, [Actions and Transformation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations) specified by Spark can be applied on RDD. Within RDD action or transformation, we do apply some of scala native operations. Each Spark API has it's own set operations. Read the link as shown in previous to get a better idea on how parallelism is achieved in the operations

**why we can't we evaluate exactly the complexity of Spark-app, and is it possible to evaluate elementary tasks complexities ?**

This article explains Map Reduce Complexity
https://web.stanford.edu/~ashishg/papers/mapreducecomplexity.pdf